# How to change the backgroundcolor in flutter (Desktop Application)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-desktop

I was trying to design a simple row and I want to change the background color

```dart
import 'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 1250, //I want to set the color here
            child: Row(
              children: [InfoLabel(label: 'label'), ], 
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could apply any of the 4 method described [here](https://androidride.com/set-background-color-in-flutter/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using on `fluent_ui` use

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FluentApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.red
      ),
    );
  }
```

And to change on a specific page, wrap with `FluentTheme`

```dart
return FluentTheme(
  data: FluentTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue
  ),
  child: ScaffoldPage(
    
  ),
);
```

**And For MaterialApp**

Use `Scaffold`'s `backgroundColor`

```dart
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red
);
```

For Full app, you can provide on  material theme

```dart
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
```

More about [using themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)

Comment: thank you so much vai, I already got it.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately below `return Scaffold(`, add `backgroundColor: Colors.black,`.

Or if you just want the `Row` having a background color, wrap it with a `Container` and set it there.

Comment: thanks but I want to do it in the flutter desktop application!

Comment: Is the `backgroundColor` attribute not available in flutter desktop? I don't know but I highly doubt that

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("Data")
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```